# Force display cursor/pointer on Android

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, drawing, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I bought a graphics tablet (Huion HS64) that works wonderfully with my S10. Only problem is that I can't see where I'm about to tap due to no cursor display. Is there any way I could force the mouse pointer to always be on or have my phone recognize the tablet as a mouse?

I could try and connect both a mouse and the tablet with a USB hub, but I'd rather a coding solution. My phone isn't rooted, but I'm not opposed to rooting to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I discover this method to show the cursor on Samsung A6+ (2018) using the Huion Pen Tablet HS64. It is not an "arrow-type cursor" but a "small-circle cursor" similar to the Samsung Note series with S pen.

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Open **About phone**
3. Under **Looking for something else?**, tap **Reset**. (If you do not see the reset, go to **General Management** and then tap **Reset**)
4. Tap **Reset setting** (just go through to make your settings can be reset)
5. Reboot the phone
6. Just do the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd steps, and then tap the **Reset Accessibility Settings** (just go through to make your accessibility settings can be reset)
7. Reboot the phone
8. Plug an OTG with a USB cord to the phone
9. Plug the USB cord to the Huion Tablet
10. The cursor will appear on the screen as a small circle

This is the method I used to my Samsung A6 plus 2018 and it worked perfectly. Now I can use my Huion Pen Tablet for my Digital Arts.

Note: I can't tell you guys if your Samsung phone can be work. I just want you to share this method. But I really hope can be work on your phone too. Please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Conash. It worked except that there is no Accessibility Reset on my Samsung A pad, but simply doing the Settings Reset fixed it for me. :-)

Comment: I just created an account only to thank Conash for his / her "guide" to reset the settings. It worked for both my wacom and huion. They were useless in my samsung tab A 8" without the pointer Ps. The developer options (pointer location) only shows what you already have "clicked". It is not useful for using pen tablets like huion and wacom

Comment: I confirm @Reeshar experience. Just resetting works. It would be nice to know *why*, though...

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on developer options(if you don't know how, you go into settings, about phone, software information, and tap on the build number a few times), and scrolling down in developer options to the one that says "pointer location". Tell me if it works.